# How to remove some repetitive pattern in word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

How to remove some repetitive pattern in word 2013? for Example, think you have copied a text from wikipedia and want to delete references numbers ([1] [2] ...) all at once. How do you do that?

I tried to use something like [*] in the replace section but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already found the'Advanced search' -> 'Use Wildcards' option, you need to use the escape character '\' because the brackets '[' and  ']' are special search tokens. Try: \[*\]

[btw: I had to use the same escape characters above to post this answer!]

https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm